# ActiveRecord many-to-many query with array of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three AR models

```
class MessageThread < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :message_threads_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :message_threads_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :message_threads_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :message_threads, through: :message_threads_users
end

class MessageThreadsUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :message_thread
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Given an array of user_ids (i.e. `[5, 6, 7]`) I want to find or create a message_thread object. I can't seem to find a good way to do this in ActiveRecord Query API.  Is there a way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to join `MessageThread` with `User` and then have a where clause. After that, if you wanted to, you can use `find` for more specificity.

Maybe like this:

```
message_thread = MessageThread.joins(:users).where(users: { id: [5, 6, 7] })
```